# Hibernating while installing Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

I clicked hibernating button while installing Ubuntu 14.04.
Then, systems seems stopped. So I reboot my laptop forcibly (mistake).

My hard disk seem broken.

I can launch 'Ubuntu without installing' through USB.

How can I recover my Windows data or other files?

Testdrive is not working in 'Ubuntu without installing'

Comment: What do you mean by "testdrive"? Also, have you tried to go ahead with the installation again? What makes you think your windows data has been compromised? Please provide more info. thanks!

Comment: I tried to go ahead with the installation many times, but it doesn't work. Since I don't see any reply, I reinstalled ubuntu.

Comment: The reason I mention testdrive is from google searching.

Comment: Please explain: how does it not work? How far do you get into the installation when it fails? What error messages, if any, do you recieve? What indicates to you that your windows data has been compromised? What indicfates to you that your drive is bad?

Comment: My situation : one partition for ubuntu (size 500GB)

Comment: Previous window partition is lost. So I tried testdrive 5 minutes ago. But it seems that it cannot recover..

Comment: is that a 500GB drive or is it on a 750GB 1TB?

Comment: My hard disk is totally 500GB.

Comment: I think that because of local internet connection, ubuntu installation is slow, so I do hibernate mistakenly.

Comment: Yeah it looks like you installed ubuntu over your widows installation. Some of that data is probably gone because it has been written over. You may be able to recover some of it using a forensic tool like testdisk or photorec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

start the application "gparted" from the live cd.

Right-click on the 500GB Ubuntu partition and select "resize / move".

Resize the partition to 250GB or half the current size.

Click on the check mark icon to apply changes.

Right-click on the "unallocated" partition, select "New", format "ext4", and then click "label" and name it "2" click the check mark icon to apply the changes.

Now, right-click on the new partiton "2". Select "resize" and make it about 2 or 4GB smaller. Click the checkmark icon to apply the changes.

Right-click on the new "unallocated" partition, select "new" and format "linux-swap". Click the checkmark icon to apply the changes.

Okay, now close gparted and click to install ubuntu. When you get to the part of the installation that asks if you would like to install Ubuntu to the entre disk or would you like to install it along side Ubuntu, select the option **"Something Else"** down at the bottom.

Here you will be taken to a window similar to gparted.

Right-click the partition labeled "2" that you created earlier and select the mount point " / " . Click continue to apply changes. Select yes for the changes to be made and continue with the installation.

This will install ubuntu to the last half of your hard disk and leave the first half where windows was installed open so you may be able to recover some of that data.

See here on data recovery https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery

Also, when the installation goes into hybernation mode, it's not really in hybernation. The screen goes black to save power but you can re-open or turn the screen back on by pressing any key on your keyboard.

If that does not work, press CTRL + ALT + F2 and then press CTRL + ALT + F7 and that should take you back to the main screen.

Comment: Thank you, but actually I have already deleted all files and re-installed.